# Converting linux path to windows path

Tags: java, linux, windows, operating-system

I'm looking for a way to map every linux directory absolute path to a windows path.
for example: whenever my app is accessing `/var/log` , it will actually access `c:/base-folder/var/log` .

My Java app was written in a way that only linux machines can run it. One of the reasons for this constraint is the filesystem paths. I cannot change all paths to a relative paths.

The solution can be in OS level (e.g running from command line `cd /var/log` will open `c:/base-folder/var/log` ) or Java level (`new File("/var/log"`) equals to `new File("c:/base-folder/var/log")` ).

Writing javaagent that changes File and Path classes is not possible, as my app is already running with different javaagent.

Using the built in ubuntu on windows won't work either, because the IDE is on windows.

Comment: What windows path *should* it access? You can't just "convert" the path - but you could literally *map* paths (with a `Map<String, String>`) and then just use the source path as a fallback if there's no mapping for it.

Comment: "What windows path should it access?" - a constant base folder. e.g. /var/log -> c:/base-folder/var/log

Regarding the map - as i said, I cannot change to many places... not feasible.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, I misunderstood. Thought it already does that and you want something else. My bad.

Comment: Maybe you can create AOP method(before call new File method()), get method's parameter, check value and replace with a new value. Yes this method may create performance issue but will work.

Comment: @Turac this is good idea! didn't thought about it. thanks!